Pressure Canning Chow Chow
I am canning chow chow and want to use my pressure canner. Can anyone tell me how many pounds as well as how long for pint and quart jars? Thank you

0 PSI for 10 minutes (boiling water bath) in pint jars. Per:
https://nchfp.uga.edu/papers/UGA_Publications/uga_pickled_products.pdf
which does not suggest using quart jars nor pressure canning this product.
While you could poke around their site and borrow times and temps for pressure canning various components of the chow-chow in pints and quarts, you'll be "not following a tested recipe" at that point, which is officially considered less than safe. Heat flow within the jar may be different and could lead to under-processing the center of the jar.
